# Returning a numeric value with hibernate @NamedNativeQuery

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I've this question:

"... if the query just returns a number (i.e., the query is something like ‘select count(id) where…..) I came up against this error

*org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported*"

For more details see: http://atechnicaljourney.wordpress.com/2012/09/30/hibernate-pure-native-scalar-queries-are-not-yet-supported/

I don't want to have a wrapper class and especially not some extra table. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: At least take some time to paste the question here instead of linking to another site.

Comment: In this case it seems redundant..

Answer (score 6):

Faced "Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported". I need to run count queries having a name of the query as parameter and one of the queries must be native SQL.
Was able to overcome by creating fake entity:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

/**
 * Simple wrapper entity work around for the limited hibernate pure native query
 * support. Where an HQL query is not possible
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@Entity
public class CountDTO  extends Number {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COUNT")
    private Long count;

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return count.doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return count.floatValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return count.intValue();
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return count.longValue();
    }

}
```

Then I set `resultClass = CountDTO.class`

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery (name="postIdSecurity",
            query="select count(...) ...", resultClass = CountDTO.class)
})
```

And get count:

```
    ((Number) getEntityManager().createNamedQuery(qryName).
setParameter(...).getSingleResult()).longValue()
```

Credits go to: http://jdevelopment.nl/hibernates-pure-native-scalar-queries-supported/#comment-1533

Answer (score 3):

You can actually do this the following way:

```
@NamedNativeQueries({
        @NamedNativeQuery(
                name = "countAll",
                query = "select count(*) from MyTable"
        )
})
public class MyTable ...


// execute like this:
((BigInteger) manager.createNamedQuery("countAll").getSingleResult()).intValue();
```

Comment: It was `java.math.BigDecimal` in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I did a work around using createQuery() instead:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-querying