# Named Native Query, execute update statement

Tags: sql, hibernate, postgresql

Can we create update statement using @NamedNativeQuery,

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "public", name = "conversion_checker")
@NamedNativeQueries({
    @NamedNativeQuery(name="updateExpireStatus", query="UPDATE conversion_checker SET status='Expired' FROM conversion_checker ")
})
public class ConversionChecker extends BaseEntity {...}
```

And here I am Executing native Query

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}}
 */
@Override
public int executeNativeUpdate(String namedNativeQuery, Map<String, Object> params) {
    Query query = getSession().getNamedQuery(namedNativeQuery);
    if(params!=null && params.size()>0){
        for(Map.Entry<String, Object> param: params.entrySet()){
            query.setParameter(param.getKey(), param.getValue());
        }
    }
    return query.executeUpdate();
}
```

it throws,

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported,
```

How to execute update statement using @NamedNativeQuery or this is not possible?

Comment: Did you look at this to

[return a value with Hibernate NamedNativeQueries](
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278544/returning-a-numeric-value-with-hibernate-namednativequery)

Comment: @vinit-prajapati And also please correct your update query. It should be like `UPDATE table_name SET properties WHERE clause`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `@NamedNativeQuery( resultClass = ConversionChecker.class )`.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about this?