# What is JPA 1.0 named native query default mapping to scalar values

Tags: java, jpa-1.0

In JPA 1.0 (TopLink Essentials) I have a native named query:

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name = "findC1andC2",
query="select c1, c2 from t1 where c3=? order by c4 desc")
```

where `c1` in Oracle DB is `number(5, 0)`, and `c2` is `number(6, 0)`.
When

```
Object object = em.createNamedQuery("findC1andC2").setParameter(1, "x").setMaxResults(1).getSingleResult();
```

following:
      `Object which getClass()` returns `java.util.Vector`

and, when:
 `java.util.Vector vector = (java.util.Vector)object;`

following:
`vector.get(0).getClass()` returns `java.math.BigDecimal`
`vector.get(1).getClass()` returns `java.math.BigDecimal`

Is is possible Long to be returned for these 2 fields i.e. where the default mapping from sql columns to java is defined?
I am aware this could be done using entity class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JPA implentations uses JDBC internally. According to [Oracle data mapping tables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14188/datamap.htm). `NUMERIC` types is mapped to `java.math.BigDecimal`.

According to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278544/returning-a-numeric-value-with-hibernate-namednativequery#answer-14042669), it's not yet possible to do pure native scalar mapping with JPA Query but you can create a Facade to be returned by the query.

I hope this helps.

Comment: In your link to Oracle data mapping tables there is JPublisher ("utility to generate Java classes to represent database entities") and it was very helpful. Further, I've been exploring JDBC standard mapping and possibilities of changing it "parametrically" (could not find it - so far). Anyhow, you answer gives very good explanation, and, therefore, is accepted. Thank you.