# Hibernate Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm working on a multimodal project and getting really frustrating error

```
I  get     org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported

Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder.bindNativeQuery(QueryBinder.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindQueries(AnnotationBinder.java:408) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:580) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
```

whatever I try executing - native queries, native named queries, queries, named queries... Always the
same error

what am I doing wrong?

Module A :

has Spring components as well as Hibernate entity classes

Module B:

Is a SpringBoot project which imports module A

Module A pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.moduleA</groupId>
    <artifactId>A</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <jaxb-and-jaxws-lib.version>2.3.3</jaxb-and-jaxws-lib.version>
        <logging.version>2.13.3</logging.version>
        <junit-jupiter-api.version>5.7.0</junit-jupiter-api.version>
        <junit-jupiter-params.version>5.7.0</junit-jupiter-params.version>
        <mockito-junit-jupiter.version>3.5.10</mockito-junit-jupiter.version>
        <cxf-xjc-plugin.version>3.3.1</cxf-xjc-plugin.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin>3.8.1</maven.compiler.plugin>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <hibernate-core.version>5.4.23.Final</hibernate-core.version>
        <hibernate-commons-annotations.version>5.1.2.Final</hibernate-commons-annotations.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate-core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Module B pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.moduleB</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <dependency.scope>provided</dependency.scope>
        <moduleA.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</moduleA.version>
        <maven.compiler.plugin>3.8.1</maven.compiler.plugin>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <spring.cloud.dependencies.version>Hoxton.SR9</spring.cloud.dependencies.version>
        <spring-jms.version>5.3.1</spring-jms.version>
        <javax.json-api.version>1.0</javax.json-api.version>
    </properties>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
    </parent>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.cloud.dependencies.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.json-api</artifactId>
        <version>${javax.json-api.version}</version>
      </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>lt.lrmuitine</groupId>
            <artifactId>moduleA</artifactId>
            <version>${moduleA.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.plugin}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Classes in module A:

```
package com.moduleA.entity;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.io.Serializable;


@NamedNativeQuery(
        name = "Test.doTest",
        query = "select 1 from test")
@Entity
@Table(name = "test")
public class Test implements Serializable {
    @Id
    private Long loid;
}

package com.moduleA.transformer;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.Tuple;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class TestTransformer {
    public List<TestDto> transform(List<Tuple> tuples) {
        List<TestDto> testDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Tuple tuple : tuples) {
            testDtoList.add(new TestDto(tuple, 1));
        }
        return testDtoList;
    }
}
```

Classes in module B

```
package com.moduleB.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class ConfigModuleB {


}


package com.moduleB;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;

@EnableJms
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.moduleB.*", "com.moduleA.*"})
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = com.moduleA.entity.Test.class)
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

and when I try to execute this class

```
package com.moduleB.pxs.dao;

import org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.Tuple;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.List;

@Component
public class TestDaoImpl implements TestDao {

    @Autowired
    private EntityManager em;

    @Autowired
    private TestTransformer testTransformer;

    public List<TestDto> getTestDto() {
        List<Test> tuples = em.createNamedQuery("Test.doTest",
                        Tuple.class);
        return testTransformer.transform(tuples);
    }

}
```

I  get org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder.bindNativeQuery(QueryBinder.java:206) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindQueries(AnnotationBinder.java:408) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:580) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.processEntityHierarchies(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:248) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.processEntityHierarchies(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:273) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1224) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1255) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.23.Final.jar!/:5.4.23.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.1.jar!/:5.3.1]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
```

Additional info:

break point on AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java: 516 line

```
    Object retVal = method.invoke(getNativeEntityManagerFactory(), args);
```

is a point in execution that which throws this error.

**Update no.1**

trying to execute

> getNativeEntityManagerFactory().getMetamodel().getEntities()

from AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java: 516 line

gives

```
org.hibernate.cfg.NotYetImplementedException: Pure native scalar queries are not yet supported
```

**Update no.2**

Trying to invoke

> em.getMetamodel().getEntities()

gives the same error

**Update no.3**

The most surprising and at the same time frustrating moment is
that if I move entity classes to Springboot project everything just
works...

**Update no.4**

It seems that this error is related to putting entity classes to a different project

**Update no.5**

The exact location of this error happens on

org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java 1255 line

```
    final SessionFactoryBuilder sfBuilder = metadata().getSessionFactoryBuilder();
```

trying to execute method metadata(), however spring boot swallows this error
and boots without an issue... Just moments later when trying to use entityManager
it shows up...

**Update no.6**

Found the culprit

> class: org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder.java;
>
> method: public static void bindNativeQuery
>
> line: 206

it seems that hibernate needs to know the resultClass otherwise it throws this error...

**Update no.7**

So, I think I found out why it throws this error... Feels like a bug from
spring-boot's side, and so

when you have your entities in a separate project in your main project (spring-boot) on main class you have to put an annotation like

`@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {myEntityFromOtherProject.class})`,

however it seems that functionality behind the

> @EntityScan

converts

> @javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery

to

> @org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery

and happens exactly that which is described in an **Update no. 6**

,However when the annotation

> @EntityScan

is not used and entity class is in the same project as spring-boot project
then no such conversion happens and hibernate just executes the code assigned
to the annotation

> javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery

which is defined in

> class: org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.java
>
> line: 411

So, I guess it's a bug... From Spring Boot perspective.

Comment: Does this: https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/workaround-jpa-hibernate-notyetimplementedexception-pure-native-scalar-queries-are-not-yet-supported/ or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278544/returning-a-numeric-value-with-hibernate-namednativequery help?

Comment: Thank you for your response, I've tried your provided solutions before posting to
stackoverflow, but they do not work for me, no matter what sql returns (1 column result or 4 column result) all is the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And so after a long debug session I came to the conclusion that I accidentally
mixed two annotations

namely

> @javax.persistence.NamedNativeQuery

and

> @org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery

removing

> @org.hibernate.annotations.NamedNativeQuery

fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the Hibernate version you are using is very old. I see you specify a version, but I guess the version is overridden by some other dependency.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now I've noticed that if I move my entity classes to spring
boot module then everything just works

Comment: and yes the version that spring boot uses upon loading is

: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.23.Final